# Conditionally Showing an apex:outputPanel

Tags: visualforce, rendered, conditional

On a custom VF page, inside of an apex:repeat component I have two apex:outputPanel components.  I want to show one apex:outputPanel when a checkbox field on the record is true/checked and I want to show the other when the checkbox field is false/unchecked.  This seems easy enough to do but I'm getting hung up on the exact syntax.

I've tried using the field itself:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!responses}" var="response" id="responseRepeat">
    <!-- show when false -->
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!NOT(response.Checkbox__c)}">
    The checkbox is false
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <!-- show when true -->
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!response.Checkbox__c}">
    The checkbox is true
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:repeat>
```

checking if the field is true or false:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!responses}" var="response" id="responseRepeat">
    <!-- show when false -->
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!response.Checkbox__c == False}">
    The checkbox is false
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <!-- show when true -->
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!response.Checkbox__c == True}">
    The checkbox is true
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:repeat>
```

and an IF statement:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!responses}" var="response" id="responseRepeat">
    <!-- show when false -->
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(response.Checkbox__c == False, true, false)}">
    The checkbox is false
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <!-- show when true -->
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(response.Checkbox__c == True, true, false)}">
    The checkbox is true
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:repeat>
```

But no luck so far as I am only able to see the first panel (show when false) even when the checkbox is true. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what exactly is the problem? doesn't it work/compile/...? does it show both panels or none?

Comment: @Christoph sorry to leave that part out. I updated the original question but the problem s that I am only able to see the first panel (show when false) even when the checkbox is true.

Comment: Looks okay. Try outputting the fields value, like
`<apex:repeat value="{!responses}" var="response" id="responseRepeat">{!response.Checkbox__c}</apex:repeat>`
Check what is being shown and if the checkbox__c is really `true`

Comment: @Christoph I'll try outputting the field value. Which of the ways that I mentioned above would be the "best" way to determine the value of the field?

Comment: Option A should do just fine

Comment: Might be a FLS issue. You don't really need two panels for this, you can just merge in the value instead. `<apex:outputPanel>{!IF(response.Checkbox__c, 'The checkbox is true', 'The checkbox is false')}</apex:outputPanel>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not have `Read` access to the field, it will always appear `false` (or perhaps `null` would be more accurate). As a side note, you do not need two `outputPanel` tags. Just use:

```
<apex:outputPanel>
    {!IF(response.Checkbox__c, 'The checkbox is true', 'The checkbox is false')}
</apex:outputPanel>
```